# Can I filter my answers on whether they are accepted or not accepted?

Tags: support, profile-page, accepted-answer

In my user profile, I can see my list of answers and I can filter by votes, activity or newest.

Is it possible to filter this list to see only the accepted answers or the not-accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

You could use a [custom search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aa%20isaccepted%3Ayes) for that though. Search on `user:me is:a isaccepted:yes` (or `no` to view unaccepted answers) .